# SQL WHERE IS NOT NULL still returns null rows

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join

I have a query where I select all records if they are not NULL but I still get results with NULL rows in it.

This is my query:

```
SELECT cnt.id, cnt.title as content_title, cnt.alias as content_alias, cnt.images, cnt.introtext, cnt.catid, cat.title as cat_title, cat.alias as cat_alias,
MAX(case when f.field_id = 2 then f.value end) as regio
FROM snm_content cnt
LEFT JOIN snm_categories cat
ON cat.id = cnt.catid
LEFT JOIN snm_fields_values f
ON cnt.id = f.item_id 
WHERE cnt.id IS NOT NULL AND f.value LIKE '%Zeeland%'
```

[image]

You can see the `IS NOT NULL` part but my database still shows all rows with NULL, why is that?

Comment: it's just returning 0 rows from the query.

Comment: Using columns from `f` in your `where` clause effectively changes your `left join` to an `inner join`. Put the `AND f.value LIKE '%Zeeland%'` in the `on` clause.  Also, the query is probably simply not returning any rows as farbiondriven wrote in his comment.

Comment: @farbiondriven But in my php loop I still get an empty item as if the code sees one result.

Comment: if you show us the raw data from the tables, and also tell us which rows you wanted the query to return, it would be a lot easier to understand the issue.

Comment: You are not keeping the rows with no null, you are keeping rows with < not null & like >. So rows with < null or not like > are kept. PS Learn what LEFT JOIN returns: INNER JOIN rows plus unmatched left table rows extended by NULLs. Always know what INNER JOIN you want as part of a LEFT JOIN. A WHERE or INNER ON that requires a right table column to be not NULL after a LEFT JOIN ON removes any rows extended by NULLs, ie leaves only INNER JOIN rows, ie "turns LEFT JOIN into INNER JOIN". You have that.

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text (including code, tables & ERDs)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use a link/image only for convenience to supplement text and/or for what cannot be given in text. And never give a diagram without a legend/key. Use edit functions to inline, not links, if you have the rep. Make your post self-contained. Please read & act on [mcve].

Comment: @philipxy Yes.... but getting a readable text version from my phpmyadmin database is impossible without spending 10 minutes to format it all correctly.

Comment: So what? PS OCR PS Typing PS Since your post should contain a [mcve], you need only cut & paste & run the code then cut & paste the output.

Comment: @philipxy Time is money my friend, 10 minutes is a waste of time when I can create an image in 30 seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably, you want a query like this:

```
SELECT cnt.id, cnt.title as content_title, cnt.alias as content_alias, cnt.images, cnt.introtext, cnt.catid, cat.title as cat_title, cat.alias as cat_alias,
       MAX(case when f.field_id = 2 then f.value end) as regio
FROM snm_content cnt LEFT JOIN
     snm_categories cat
     ON cat.id = cnt.catid LEFT JOIN
     snm_fields_values f
     ON cnt.id = f.item_id AND f.value LIKE '%Zeeland%'
WHERE cnt.id IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY cnt.id;
```

You have an aggregation query with no `GROUP BY`.  This would be an error in any other database.  If we assume that `cnt.id` is unique, then you can safely aggregate by that.

The other issue is the comparison to `f.value`.  That should be in the `ON` clause, if you really intend a `LEFT JOIN`.